# Why is this alternating sequence converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image: Problem]

the alternating sequence converges when (n+1)th term is less than nth term right?
and in this case, when n is 1
the term is 1/3
and when n is 2, which is n+1
the term is 1/2, but this is larger than the first term. How come this converges?

Answer (score 2):

A series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is convergent if and only if there is some $N$ such that the tailing series $\sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k$ is convergent. Therefore, for Leibniz criterion you can make do with the sequence $\{\lvert a_k\rvert\}_{k\ge 1}$ being *eventually* decreasing, not necessarily "globally" decreasing.

Comment: aha "eventually" is the key. thank you !